# Insertion Sort of a linked list of strings

Tags: c

So I am using an insertion sort to sort a data file of words alphabetically.
Example data file:
Ryan
John
Casey
....
Etc

When I get to line 83. printList(head); I get blank lines of data where my correct data should be.
This was originally used for integers but decided to switch it to strings to practice for my upcoming final.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
  #include<string.h> 
/* Link list node */
struct Node 
{ 
    char data[10]; 
    struct Node* next; 
}; 


void sortedInsert(struct Node** head_ref, struct Node* new_node) 
{ 
    struct Node* current; 
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->data >= new_node->data) 
    { 
        new_node->next = *head_ref; 
        *head_ref = new_node; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref; 
        while (current->next!=NULL && 
               current->next->data < new_node->data) 
        { 
            current = current->next; 
        } 
        new_node->next = current->next; 
        current->next = new_node; 
    } 
} 



/* A utility function to create a new node */
struct Node *newNode(char new_data[]) 
{ 
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node =  (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->data  == new_data; 
    new_node->next =  NULL; 

    return new_node; 
} 

/* Function to print linked list */
void printList(struct Node *head) 
{ 
    struct Node *temp = head; 
    while(temp != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", temp->data); 
        temp = temp->next; 
    } 
} 

/* Drier program to test count function*/
int main() 
{ 
    char word[10];
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct Node* head = NULL; 
    FILE *data;
    if((data = fopen("./hw11.data","r"))==NULL){
    printf("error-hw11.data could not be opened.\n");  
    return 0;
  }
  //insert words into linked list

  while(1){
    if(feof(data)) break;
    fgets(word,10,data);
    printf("%s\n",word);
   struct Node *new_node = newNode(word);
   sortedInsert(&head,new_node);

  }
    printf("\n Created Linked List\n"); 
    printList(head); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Note:you dont *need* the special case.

Answer (score 4):

instead of assignment = , you are using == operator in newNOde()

```
struct Node *newNode(char new_data[]) 
{ 
/* allocate node */
struct Node* new_node =  (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

/* put in the data  */
new_node->data  == new_data;  // **it should = (single) NOT == to assign**
new_node->next =  NULL; 

return new_node; 
}
```